# Android Asynchronous Http Client - Can't install on Mac OS 10.10.5

Tags: android, rest, http, asynchronous, loopj

I just downloaded the main Java Jar file directly from here: http://loopj.com/android-async-http/
Double-clicked the jar file and got this error message pop up:

```
"The Java JAR file "android-async-http-1.4.9.jar" could not be launched.
Check the Console for possible error messages."
```

In the console, it had the following 4 messages pop up:

```
4/23/16 7:34:40.805 AM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.quicklookd.2848) Path not allowed in target domain: type = pid, path = /Library/Frameworks/iTunesLibrary.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/com.apple.iTunesLibraryService.xpc error = 147: The specified service did not ship in the requestor's bundle, origin = /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/Versions/A/Resources/quicklookd.app
4/23/16 7:34:53.261 AM QuickLookSatellite[2861]: [QL] Using too much memory (127 MB), hit critical threshold (120 MB), exiting immediately to clean up.
4/23/16 7:34:53.280 AM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.quicklook.satellite.2CBCE90F-159F-4B12-83D8-1859B1F39063[2861]) Service exited due to signal: Killed: 9
4/23/16 7:34:53.597 AM QuickLookSatellite[2879]: ImageIO: JPEG Corrupt JPEG data: 1502 extraneous bytes before marker 0xfe
4/23/16 7:34:53.600 AM QuickLookSatellite[2879]: ImageIO: JPEG JPEG datastream contains no image
```

For reference, I've confirmed that in my mac security, I've switched it to "allow apps downloaded from anywhere," so that shouldn't be an issue.

In addition, I suspect the last two are related to the actual image of the pop-up error (the first thing I reported)... so once the root cause is resolved, there shouldn't be a need for an error message and everything should be dandy.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This jar file is Android library, it is not application file ==> You can not run this file.

Comment: I see. That's incredibly useful. Can you tell me where the "right" place to set it up? Should I just a) download the file from the android device and try downloading and opening it there? Or b) am I supposed to put it in a specific directory of the Android App which I'm building?